# SQL Code to Determine IF Test Date of (A) is Within N Days of Test Date (B) then Return Members Row with Both Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

I'm writing a SQL query in Teradata to determine which members had an eGFR and uACR test done within 4 days of each other. All of the tests are being pulled in correctly, but not sure who to go about this in the WHERE clause.
[SQL Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO0Nf.png)

I only need data returned where this is true.

I tried this

```
AND [uACR_2b_2_DATE] <= ([uACR_2b_1_DATE] + 4 Days)
```

also
[other attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndnaw.png)

[sample code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTPYp.png)

Comment: The syntax for SQL Server is very different from the syntax for Teradata, please choose just one.

Comment: Please read [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: If it's actually a DATE it's simple:`AND uACR_2b_2_DATE <= uACR_2b_1_DATE + 4` If it's a timestamp you need Standard SQL interval syntax`AND uACR_2b_2_DATE <= uACR_2b_1_DATE + interval '4' day`

Comment: Oh, it's Teradata and sorry, I didn't know I shouldn't upload an image for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql server there is DATEDIFF to determine the distance, this works with days, hours, etc.

```
DECLARE
 @dt1 DATETIME = '20230102 23:59:59' 
 ,@dt2 DATETIME = '20230103 00:00:00'


SELECT difference_ABS = ABS( DATEDIFF(DAY, @dt1, @dt2) )
```

This ignores the time part, and gives the absolute (no negatives) of the distance of the date part. So in this example You get one day distance, although the two timestamps are one minute apart. If this is what You would like to use, just put it in a `WHERE-CLAUSE` like so

```
ABS( DATEDIFF(DAY, uACR_2b_1_DATE, uACR_2b_2_DATE) ) <= 4
```

Comment: I tried this one but got an error message that something was missing between "(" and "DAY"

Comment: Just checked it again (in sql server), and it worked. For Teradata help can be found under this link: https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Functions-Operators-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2017/DateTime-and-Interval-Functions-and-Expressions/Arithmetic-Operators-and-ANSI-DateTime-and-Interval-Data-Types/Examples/Example-Calculating-the-Difference-in-Days-Between-DATE-Values